# Setting top position whilst modal visible

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/y084vkzs/

The problem is when I stop scrolling the position of my modal is not where the page currently is at.

I've been following and improving upon [this tutorial](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery).

1. Calling it is easy! This part is in my page itself;

   ```
   $('.paulund_modal_2').paulund_modal_box({
       title:'Second Title Box',
       description:'PHP content resides here...',
   });
   ```
2. Position from the top, just add;

   ```
   top: 'NUMpx',
   ```

   or

   ```
   top: 'NUM%',
   ```

I've recently added a stop page scroll event I call when you click to open up the modal. This means I need to set minimum top position to;

```
var top = $('html').offset().top;
```

however setting;

```
top: top + 'px',
```

has no effect whatsoever.

Complete Script .JS

```
(function($){

    // Defining our jQuery plugin
    $.fn.paulund_modal_box = function(prop){

    // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
    // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
    var keys = [37, 38, 39, 40];

        function preventDefault(e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          if (e.preventDefault)
              e.preventDefault();
          e.returnValue = false;  
        }

        function keydown(e) {
            for (var i = keys.length; i--;) {
                if (e.keyCode === keys[i]) {
                    preventDefault(e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        function wheel(e) {
          preventDefault(e);
        }

        function disable_scroll() {
          if (window.addEventListener) {
              window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
          }
          window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
          document.onkeydown = keydown;
        }

        function enable_scroll() {
            if (window.removeEventListener) {
                window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
            }
            window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
        }

        var top = $('html').offset().top;

        var options = $.extend({
            height : "250",
            width : "500",
            title:"JQuery Modal Box Demo",
            description: "Example of how to create a modal box."
        },prop);

        return this.click(function(e){
            var top = $('html').offset().top;
            alert(top);
            e.preventDefault();
            disable_scroll();
            add_block_page();
            add_popup_box();
            add_styles();
            $('.paulund_modal_box').fadeIn();
        });

         function add_styles(){         
            $('.paulund_modal_box').css({ 
                'position':'absolute', 
                'left':options.left,
                'top':options.top,
                'display':'none',
                'height': options.height + 'px',
                'width': options.width + 'px',
                'border':'1px solid #fff',
                'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
                'background': '#f2f2f2', 
                'z-index':'50',
                'overflow':'hidden'
            });
            $('.paulund_modal_close').css({
                'position':'relative',
                'top':'-25px',
                'left':'20px',
                'float':'right',
                'display':'block',
                'height':'50px',
                'width':'50px',
                'background': 'url(images/close.png) no-repeat',
            });
                        /*Block page overlay*/
            var pageHeight = $(document).height();
            var pageWidth = $(window).width();

            $('.paulund_block_page').css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'top':'0',
                'left':'0',
                'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
                'height':pageHeight,
                'width':pageWidth,
                'z-index':'10'
            });
            $('.paulund_inner_modal_box').css({
                'background-color':'#fff',
                'height':(options.height - 50) + 'px',
                'width':(options.width - 50) + 'px',
                'padding':'10px',
                'margin':'15px',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px'
            });
        }

         function add_block_page(){
            var block_page = $('<div class="paulund_block_page"></div>');

            $(block_page).appendTo('body');
        }

         function add_popup_box(){
             var pop_up = $('<div class="paulund_modal_box"><a href="#" class="paulund_modal_close"></a><div class="paulund_inner_modal_box"><h2>' + options.title + '</h2><p>' + options.description + '</p></div></div>');
             $(pop_up).appendTo('.paulund_block_page');

             $('.paulund_modal_close').click(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
                $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut().remove();                 
             });
        }

        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can we see the complete code JS please?

Comment: Thanks for editing @Joe, was having problems there!

Comment: Why do you have `var top = $('html').offset().top;` twice?

Comment: Left that in just now trying to figure out, copy and pasting sorry

Comment: This is quite a lot of code, perhaps if you could make a demo you'd get a quicker answer.

Comment: Also, I can't see where you're using the `top + 'px'`

Comment: Under the `return this.click(function(e){` so when they click `<a href="#" class="paulund_modal_2">Click Here</a>` it checks the scroll from top position. I also tried adding it to the html part `top : top + 'px'` however adding an alert under the click event returns 0...

Comment: Do you mean `'top':options.top` is the problem?

Comment: [just made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y084vkzs/)

Comment: `var top = $('html').offset().top;` isn't in the fiddle?

Comment: I felt the need not to add as it was not working. Just made [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/sv9bsmb5/) for you.

Comment: Cheers. Perhaps I'm still missing something, but if I look at the console, I get `Cannot read property 'offset' of null`...Isn't that a clue?

Comment: Yes, I have had this on an alert in several places. I do not know how to trigger how far from the top is upon click to set the position from the top a minimum of that from the top.

Comment: So I've found adding an alert in the click event to show `$(window).scrollTop();` shows the correct position but setting it I have yet to discover.

Comment: How about using that instead of offset when you set var  top?

Comment: Tried but failing to pass the var in the on click event. It called the styles like so `add_styles();`...

Answer (score 0):

Discovering the following did not find the position from the top;

```
var top = $('html').offset().top;
```

I dug deeper for an answer and found the following worked;

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

I defined from_top outside of the click event to make it global then upon click set it and in the styles section added the variable and hey-presto!